# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_image_srcset selects the wrong image based on media size

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, responsive-images

I'm using Wordpress and want to display the right image size based on wp_get_attachment_image_srcset.
The browser is changing images as I resize, but not working with the steps it should.

These are my sizes in functions.php

```
add_image_size('s320', 320, 240, true);
add_image_size('s640', 640, 480, true);
add_image_size('s992', 992, 744, true);
add_image_size('s1280', 1280, 960, true);
add_image_size('s2000', 2000, 1500, true);
add_image_size('s2600', 2600, 1950, true);
```

And on my index.php, I set sizes as 100vw when under 768 one column and if bigger, two columns. wp_get_attachment_image_srcset sets this dimensions for srcset

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAMPDwwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="
    srcset="...image-2000x1500.jpg 2000w,
    ...image-50x38.jpg 50w,
    ...image-320x240.jpg 320w, 
    ...image-640x480.jpg 640w, 
    ...image-992x744.jpg 992w, 
    ...image-1280x960.jpg 1280w"
    sizes="
            (max-width: 768px) 100vw,
        (max-width: 2000px) 50vw,
        2000px" 
    alt="Alt-text" class="lazyLoad img-fluid">
```

What the browser is doing is:

```
for a screen < 226: displays currentSrc as 320
225 < screen < 398: as 640
397 < screen < 564: as 992
563 < screen < 1599: as 1280
and then display as 2000
```

The steps seem to be working with no logic to me... I want the browser to follow my steps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be better suited to post at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks, maybe you are right. Just did it. If anyone wants to follow it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311674/wordpress-wp-get-attachment-image-srcset-selects-the-wrong-image-based-on-media

Comment: On wordpress.stackexchange.com, they respond that my problem seems to be with browser and sizes and therefe, not related with Wordpress because srcset is output the right way. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the true at the end and add priority like that :

```
add_image_size('s320', 320, 240, false, 9999);
```

Comment: Didn't have any effect, still working the same. Still, the browser's steps make sense?

Comment: Have you an url to see the issue ? Maybe the CSS erase the size of your image and add new size on it.

Comment: No, I'm on xampp on localhost. I'm starting fresh with this wordpress and pretty much the only css is bootstrap-reboot and bootstrap-grid